# Understanding negative definite/semidefinite functions

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, control-theory

I'm working on control theory and have some difficulty understanding if a function is negative definite or semidefinite.

Given the system

$\dot{x_1} = -x_2^2$

$\dot{x_2} = -x_1^2x_2 + x_1^3 - x_2$

How do I determine if

$-x_1^2x_2^4 - x_2^4$

is negative definite or negative semidefinite?

Comment: "negative-definite" as applied to a function has different meaning in different contexts.  Is [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_function#Most_common_usage) the one you're working with?

Comment: Take $x_1 = 1$ and $x_2 = 0$. Then clearly your expression equals $0$ although $(x_1, x_2) = (1, 0) \neq (0, 0)$. Therefore, your expression is negative semi-definite.

Answer (score 1):

Is there $(x_1, x_2) \neq (0,0)$ such that the function attains $0$? If so, it is semidefinite.

Note that I don't know your definition, I'm just guessing by the usual definition for bilinear forms.